# converting 13-digit unixtime in ms to timestamp in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I want to convert 13-digit Unix-time in milliseconds to the timestamp :

"1523126888080"==>> %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

I have tried the following code from this [link](http://foo.com),
 But I think this is for 10-digit Unix-time and I am having 13-digit Unix-time. So,

This code is working, But it is giving the wrong results and wrong time:

```
import time
time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1523126888080".strip()[0:9])))

Output: '1974-10-30 02:34:48'
Expected: '2018-04-08 12:18:08'
```

But this one is giving error:

```
import time
time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1523126888080")))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1523126888080")))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a millisecond-precise timestamp so first divide it by `1000` then feed it to [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) for local timezone (or pass [`datetime.tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) of the target timezone as a second argument) or [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) for UTC. Finally, use [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to turn it into a string of your desired format.

```
import datetime

timestamp = "1523126888080"
your_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp)/1000)  # using the local timezone
print(your_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))  # 2018-04-07 20:48:08, YMMV
```

Answer (score 4):

Try dividing `1523126888080` by `1000` to get a valid timestamp.
You should also use `%d` instead of `%D` as argument for `strftime`, i.e:

```
import time
ts = 1523126888080 / 1000
print(time.strftime("%d %H:%M", time.localtime(ts)))
# 29 21:04
```

Comment: if I need to get the timestamps that are 300 ms before and after the given "1523126888080", so just I subtract and add the value "300000" to that given timestamp? How can I do this with python code?

Comment: Please open a new question and paste the link here, I'll try to help you.

Comment: I posted a question  here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063039/compute-a-timestamps-based-on-13-digit-unixtime-timestamp-in-ms-in-python

Could you answer it?