# compute a timestamps based on 13-digit unixtime timestamp in ms in python

Tags: python

I want to compute the timestamp that is 300 milliseconds before and after the given 13-digit unixtime of the system. I checked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710963/converting-13-digit-unixtime-in-ms-to-timestamp-in-python) to convert 13-digit unixtime to timestamp.

Then, given the timestamp, I wrote a simple code in python to double-check whether the outputs are correct or not.

Assume the given timestamp of the system is 13-digit unixtime and equal to X = "1396226255964". Now I need to compute the new timestamp "Y1" that is "300 milliseconds" before X and "Y2" that is "300 milliseconds" after X.

Is this code computes Y1 & Y2 correctly?

```
X = "1396226255964"
Y1 = int(X) - int (300000)
print("Y1:", Y1)
Y2 = int(X) + int (300000)
print("Y2:", Y2)
```

Outputs: 
Y1: 1396225955964
Y2: 1396226556620

Comment: You may need to convert it to `datetime` and then subtract it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

13-digit Unix-time is already in millisecond, so if you want to get 300 milliseconds or after, you only need to:

```
X = "1396226255964"
Y1 = int(X) - 300
print("Y1:", Y1)
Y2 = int(X) + 300
print("Y2:", Y2)
```

This is a bit unusual, X is usually supposed to be integer.

Comment: Oh, that it is fine. Are you sure from this?

Comment: I'm 100% sure about this. Anyway, about the integer or int, your choice @MohsenAli

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

X = "1396226255964"

X_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(X)/1000)  # using the local timezone

y1= X_dt + timedelta(milliseconds=300)
y2 = X_dt + timedelta(milliseconds=-300)

print(X_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
print(y1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
print(y2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
```

Comment: But I need to get the outputs y1 and y2 in the form of 13 digits unixtime same as X. How I do this?