# How do you convert TD Ameritrade's API time stamp to pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I am trying to use a pandas dataframe to create a time series visualization from stock price data I pulled from TD Ameritrade's API. In order to do this, I've been trying to convert the timestamps in the `datetime` column of my dataframe to datetime objects. This way, I can set datetime column as the new index and have visualization with a cleanly formatted x-axis.

```
       open    high     low   close  volume       datetime
0    336.89  336.90  336.69  336.77   26232  1599822000000
1    336.90  337.05  336.69  336.92   13180  1599822300000
2    336.98  337.24  336.98  337.23   31810  1599822600000
3    337.01  337.25  337.00  337.15    8749  1599822900000
4    337.10  337.10  336.70  336.70    9664  1599823200000
..      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...            ...
```

I've tried achieving this via the advice in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710963/converting-13-digit-unixtime-in-ms-to-timestamp-in-python) to no avail. I've also tried using the following code:

```
df['adj_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df['datetime']/1000))
```

However, this is the result:

```
       open    high  ...       datetime                  adj_datetime
0    336.89  336.90  ...  1599822000000 1970-01-01 00:00:01.599822000
1    336.90  337.05  ...  1599822300000 1970-01-01 00:00:01.599822300
2    336.98  337.24  ...  1599822600000 1970-01-01 00:00:01.599822600
3    337.01  337.25  ...  1599822900000 1970-01-01 00:00:01.599822900
4    337.10  337.10  ...  1599823200000 1970-01-01 00:00:01.599823200
..      ...     ...  ...            ...                           ...
```

This is not the result I am looking for because 1.) this data is from 2020-09-11 and 2.) this is not extended hours trading data so 12:01 AM is not the appropriate time.

Any advice, feedback, or additional resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These look like Javascript timestamps (milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC).  But all the times are rounded down modulo 1000 seconds, which is really weird. Ask the people who supplied your data about  that. At any rate you may need to convert these to the correct time zone; they're probably in UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

Default time unit in [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime) is in nanosecond (ns) but your `datetime` column has timestamps in millisecond (ms).

### Solution

Specify parameter `unit=ms` so `pd.to_datetime` interprets timestamps correctly.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1599822000000, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2020-09-11 11:00:00')
```

Could also use [pd.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(1599822000000, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2020-09-11 11:00:00')
```